# Multiple input file tags with IOS 6+ on iPad/iPhone

Tags: ios, html, asp-classic, ios7

EDIT :

I've been able to resolve this, after finding that iOS uploads every image as "image.jpg". In freeASPUpload.asp, I changed the following :

```
For Each fileItem In UploadedFiles.Items
        filePath = path & fileItem.FileName
        Set streamFile = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        streamFile.Type = adTypeBinary
        streamFile.Open
        StreamRequest.Position=fileItem.Start
        StreamRequest.CopyTo streamFile, fileItem.Length
        streamFile.SaveToFile path & FileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        streamFile.close
        Set streamFile = Nothing
        fileItem.Path = filePath
     Next
```

To :

```
For Each fileItem In UploadedFiles.Items
        FileName = GetFileName(path, fileItem.FileName)
        fileItem.FileName = FileName
        filePath = path & fileItem.FileName
        Set streamFile = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        streamFile.Type = adTypeBinary
        streamFile.Open
        StreamRequest.Position=fileItem.Start
        StreamRequest.CopyTo streamFile, fileItem.Length
        streamFile.SaveToFile path & FileName, adSaveCreateOverWrite
        streamFile.close
        Set streamFile = Nothing
        fileItem.Path = filePath
     Next
```

This is within the save function of the script. The GetFileName function iterates over what is in the folder already, and adds a number until it is unique. It then updates the file key to its new name. I've left an "image.jpg" file in the temp folder, so that it always finds one. That works for now.

What I've found, however, is for some reason, it flips the second photo out of the five that the form allows for..

I will try to fix that / look for others with the same issue. I've always had problems with iPhones and iPads rotating pictures, and it's never consistent.

---

I'm trying to grab multiple files from a mobile fleet of iPads and iPhones. Currently I have 5

```
<input type="file" name="fileX" accept="image/*">
```

This works fine in a browser (using free asp upload / classic ASP). In testing, it works with IOS, but only if I send one file. If I send more then one via the form, I get the error 'file not found'. It seems like the files aren't being sent at all.

The file not found kicks back when trying to manipulate the file via FSO.

Uploads here :

```
Dim Upload, fileName, fileSize, ks, i, fileKey
Set Upload = New FreeASPUpload
SaveFiles = ""


  uploadsDirVar = "directory"
  Upload.Save(uploadsDirVar)

  ks = Upload.UploadedFiles.keys
```

Errors out here :

```
Set f=fs.GetFile(uploadsDirVar & "\" & Upload.UploadedFiles(fileKey).FileName)
```

Any ideas on how I can get around this? Everything I've read points towards the HTML5 multiple tag on a single input. However, in my scenario, this won't work. I'm also tying descriptions for the images to the fields based on field name, restricting the upload to 5, re-sizing the images on the action page before passing it to its final destination and attaching them to an email.

Any advice welcome, and thank you for your time!

**Edit

The issue seems to be that IOS names all uploads "image", coming from either the camera or the library. Now the problem is how to rename the image before the script attempts to upload it. From what I'm understanding, it needs to happen within the asp upload component before it places the file.

Comment: Does free asp upload support uploading multiple files? I seem to recall not every upload component I used had that ability...

Comment: It does, and does it automatically. See the above edit - the issue seems to be that IOS is naming all of the uploads "image.xxx" regardless of where they come from. Thanks for posting!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the above edit for the answer. As for the flipped images - turns out they are flipped straight from the iPad. I checked the exif data and I'm not sure how to account for this in my system. If I find the answer, I'll post here.